edge detect : geometry node
the tree, in the image below, of Geometry node is a displace.
How can I perform an edge detect to apply the displace changes only to the edges? without disregarding the displacement of the rest of the mesh?

select the edges of an object like we do in materials (see image below) but in Geometry Nodes?

thanks

'Edges'? Do you mean the boundary of your mesh? Could you illustrate the edges you mean, please?

Do you mean to select edges that have an angle as opposed to all edges?

I would like to select edges to apply displacement only to them

Maybe someone would find a better method, but this is how I would do it - but I do not know what your base object is, if it is a simple cube with only 8 vertices and 12 edges or maybe has a higher resolution. I used the simple default cube as base.
Then I first subdivide it to get a higher resolution for displacement and determine the distance of the new vertices from the original edges with a Geometry Proximity node set to Edges.

Next I use a Map Range node to swap 0 and 1 in the To Min/To Max values to make a mask for the displacement effect, while the From Max value is used to set how far the effect should reach. By the way, setting a To Max > 0 can be used if you want a little displacement overall additionally to the edges.

A Noise Texture plugged in a Vector Math node set to Subtract 0.5 on all channels will be used for displacing the mesh. This noise gets scaled by the Map Range > Result with a Vector Math > Scale node.

Then the vector can be used as Offset in a Set Position node to displace the edges. Another Scale node can be used to change the strength of the displacement, although you could also do this by changing the To Min value in the Map Range node.

Finally you might optionally add a Subdivision Surface node and a Set Shade Smooth node to further modify the displacement.

However, this does not work really well if you would bevel an edge and the face is then angled 45° degrees on relative to the X, Y or Z axis. I'm not sure why and if I find out I'll edit my answer.

Thank you for your help
but what you did is like a bump and I want more wear like a boolean . can you help me ? see the link:https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/0/e/1/0e1be561757da87bf9086f99e8652451493a7e50.png

Well, you asked for displacement which is not cutting off of edges. What you mean is an edge wear effect... there are many tutorials on this, here is one for example: Geometry Nodes - Edge Wear

Thanks for the help, but I want to wear the edges at the mesh level with boolean through Geometry nodes, like in this link: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/0/e/1/0e1be561757da87bf9086f99e8652451493a7e50.png

Ah okay, yeah sorry. Then try this one from Cartesian Caramel: Edge Damage with Geometry Nodes
